# Counters get overflowed; issue with GetLastInputInfo()

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Counters get overflowed; issue with GetLastInputInfo

I want to check for user inactivity in my application using GetLastInputInfo and Environment. TickCount.

It's working properly, but after 24 days, 20 hours, and 31 minutes since the last reboot, counters get overflowed, and the last input taken as LastInput is taken as 4,294,966 seconds before "DateTime. Now".

```
private struct Lastinputinfo
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public readonly int dwTime;
    }
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static DateTime LastInput => SystemStartup.AddMilliseconds(LastInputTicks);
public static TimeSpan IdleTime => DateTime.Now.Subtract(LastInput);

private static int LastInputTicks
    {
        get
    {
var lii = new Lastinputinfo { cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Lastinputinfo))  };
GetLastInputInfo(ref lii);
return lii.dwTime;
    }
    }
```

Is there a way to tackle this? Any suggestions on how to test this, too?

Comment: Change int to long.

Comment: @jdweng They use the Win32 method GetLastInputInfo which expects a structure containing the tick as 32 bit value. You canot change this.

Comment: dwTime is DWORD in LASTINPUTINFO. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-lastinputinfo It can be doubled by using uint rather than int. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount

Comment: With uint it will double to approximately 50 days before it rolls over.